# How to dynamically bind a Query to a grid?

Tags: grid, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a Query that the datasources it is set to can change dynamically. I want to take the results of this Query and bind that to a Grid, so each time it may have new fields, and data.

I already added a Grid to my form, and added the Common table as a datasource. I tried to set the dataSource of the grid, and iterate through the fields and dynamically add them, but no data is showing up.

Comment: Could you provide some of your code as a sample? It would make it easier to determine what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look on the form `SysTableBrowser`.
It builds the grid based on a `tableId`.

Maybe you can change `SysTableBrowser` to accept a query.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, that was where I started. It accomplishes it very differently by using the compiler to compile the query you type into the text box below. I can not seem to get the query from the Query object (in a format that will compile) so I do not think that will work.

Comment: You should be able to change the auto-generated query to your instead. Do so in the `init` method of the datasource: this.query(yourquery);

Comment: Ok, so after a lot of research, yes this does what I want. I got it working, but now it is just an issue of trying to figure out how to display the results in a format that makes sense, as the Query will have multiple tables, where the table browser does not.

Comment: If you have inner joined the tables, you should be able to display all the fields in the grid. But would the end result make sense to the user?